# Without using promo codes, how do I give users, who already purchased specific product, another product for free?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

Here is the case:

- I have 3 in-app products (1 is new)
- I want to run a promo where users can buy just 2 and get all the three.
- The problem is some users already purchased 2 products before the promo (I also want them to have the third product).
- I'm thinking of creating a new SKU where if users purchase it, all three will be unlocked but that will exclude the previous premium users.

I don't think Google Play supports this (or does it?) so can anyone suggest a logic (code or anything?) to get this done?

Thank you.

Comment: Apparently you can check order history so that should get you what you need right? "You can request product details from Google Play, issue orders for in-app products, and quickly retrieve ownership information based on users' purchase history. "

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say? Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239871/android-in-app-check-if-an-item-has-been-purchased